# Clear Session in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, session

I want to clear the session on Page unload.

Here is a condition :

- If user goes from Page A to Page B of the same site session must not get cleared.
- If user close the browser window or Tab(close the site),session must gets cleared.

I have tried using AJAX PageMethod to call server-side procedure to remove session from client side script.But the procedure is not getting hit,I have checked it using Breakpoint.

server side procedure is in master.cs file

I will appreciate your help.

Here is code in site.master

```
<body onunload="HandleClose();">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function HandleClose()
        {            
            PageMethods.AbandonSessions();
        }
```

and here is a code in master.cs :

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static void AbandonSessions()
        {

            HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register a javascript event for page unload and send an AJAX request to clear the session. This event will be trigerred when the user closes the browser window or tab. Here's an [example page](http://www.dcs.uwaterloo.ca/~anderson/JavaScript/ex_load_unload.html):

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function clearSession() {
    // TODO: Send an AJAX call to a server side script 
    // that will clear the session
}
</script> 

</head> 
<body onunload="clearSession();"> 

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: I did the same,but the server procedure not getting hit.

Comment: Could you try sending the request with jQuery and enable synchronous request?

Comment: jQuery will do the same thing.

Comment: Not the same if you set the `async` parameter to false.